# UWP Crash on ContinuousRecognitionSession_Completed without error

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone, win-universal-app, speech-recognition

I am using Microsoft's speech recognition library in a UWP app. Speech Recognition works fine on the Desktop. However, when it runs on the Windows Phone the application crashes when it enters ContinuousRecognitionSession_Completed.

```
   private void ContinuousRecognitionSession_Completed(SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession sender, SpeechContinuousRecognitionCompletedEventArgs args) 
    { 
        //Code stuff
    }
```

Then the application on the phone crashes without error. Visual Studio will continue to run for some time before giving an exit code. When I do get an exit code I receive either 'Access Violation', I believe the code is '0xc0000005', or a Breakpoint Exception.

I am at my wits end and if anyone has a tip on how to fix this it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue. My environment is window 10 build 14393, Lumia 640. Please test the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis) on your side.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT The sample works fine. Do you think it could be an issue with Template 10 and Speech?

Comment: I'm not sure with out a reproduced project. You may go to template 10 to find if there is an issue similar as you.